# Ошибка в парсере: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, openpyxl

```
import requests
import bs4
import openpyxl
# -------------------
#   CHANGING VALUES
# -------------------
insColumn = 7  # в какой столбец вставлять
insRow = 3  # с какой строки начинать вставлять
classSelectorCOST = '.viewbull-summary-price__value.inplace'
fileName = 'Аналитика.xlsx'
# -------------------
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=fileName)  # открываем файл книги
sheet = wb['Лист1']  # выбираем нужный лист книги
for idx in sheet['H3':'H5']:
    for cell in idx:  
        if cell.value is None:
            print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' not complete')
            insRow += 1
        else:
            s = requests.get(cell.value)  # получение данных с URL
            b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
            pr = b.find_all(classSelectorCOST)  # селектор класса в html странице
            if pr is None:
                print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' not complete')
                insRow += 1
            else:
                sheet.cell(row=insRow, column=insColumn).value = pr[0]  
                print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' complete')
                insRow += 1
wb.save(fileName)
```

Парсер веб-страниц, берёт ссылки из одних ячеек excel и записывает в другие значение со страницы. Выполняется проверка наличия ссылки в ячейке и наличия класса на странице.

При выполнении ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aleksey/Google Диск/pythonLearn/pyProject/parsingCost.py", line 27, in <module>
    sheet.cell(row=insRow, column=insColumn).value = pr[0]  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Как выглядят классы на сайте для парсинга:

```
<span class="viewbull-summary-price__value inplace" data-field="price">
500
    <i class='currency currency__rub'>&#8381;</i>
</span>
```

Comment: Похоже, что в коде страницы нет элементов с классом `.viewbull-summary-price__value.inplace`.

Comment: Данный элемент есть, проверил. Мне кажется проблема не в этом.

Comment: Как проверяли? Ошибка "list index out of range" говорит, что список короче индекса, по которому вы обращаетесь. Для индекса 0 это означает, что список пуст. Метод `find_all` возвращает пустой список, если не нашёл элементов соответствующих селектору.

Comment: Если использовать парсер без всех проверок, он находит этот селектор и вынимает значение.

Comment: Скорее всего, защищаясь от частых и/или однообразных запросов, сервер начинает отдавать какую-то заглушку, на которой нет элементов соответствующих селектору. Попробуйте перед `requests.get` поставить задержку в несколько секунд или делать каждый запрос через отдельный прокси.

Comment: Прямо сейчас запустил другой парсер с этого же сайта, по тем же самым страницам и всё работает. Никаких заглушек нет, все значения приходят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вот рабочий вариант:**

```
import requests
import bs4
import openpyxl
# -------------------
#   CHANGING VALUES
# -------------------
insColumn = 7  # в какой столбец вставлять
insRow = 3  # с какой строки начинать вставлять
classSelectorCOST = 'span.viewbull-summary-price__value.inplace'
fileName = 'Аналитика.xlsx'
# -------------------
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=fileName)  # открываем файл книги
sheet = wb['Лист1']  # выбираем нужный лист книги
for idx in sheet['H3':'H231']:  # получаем массив ссылок
    for cell in idx:  
        if cell.value is None:
            print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' not complete, no URL')
            insRow += 1
        else:
            s = requests.get(cell.value)  # получение данных с URL
            b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")  
            pr = b.select(classSelectorCOST)  # селектор класса в html странице
            if pr:
                price = pr[0].getText()
                sheet.cell(row=insRow, column=insColumn).value = price[:-1]
                print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' complete')
            else:
                print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' not complete, no tag')
            insRow += 1
wb.save(fileName)
```

Поменял `pr = b.find_all(classSelectorCOST)` на `pr = b.select(classSelectorCOST)`

и добавил:

```
price = pr[0].getText()
sheet.cell(row=insRow, column=insColumn).value = price[:-1]
```

Всё заработало, отрабатывает пустые ячейки и неправильно отображаемые страницы. Документацию изучил, так и не понял чем методы select и find_all отличаются.

Comment: Молодец, что сами разобрались! Раз работает, то и ладно...

Comment: Так то да, но вот бы найти внятную документацию по bs4, а то в интернете каждая статья по нему друг другу противоречит.

Comment: Понял... find_all ищет по названию тега, а в параметрах можно атрибуты передавать, типо class, id, и т.п. А select принимает строку в css-selector. Вот поэтому и работает

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о выходе индекса за границы

> IndexError: list index out of range

и, судя по стеку ошибки, произошла в `pr[0]`

---

Поменяйте проверку `if pr is None:` на `if not pr:`, т.к. согласно [описанию метода find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all), если не будут найдены теги, он вернет пустой список. А пустой список не является `None`.

Пример исправления:

```
        ...

        if pr:
            sheet.cell(row=insRow, column=insColumn).value = pr[0]  
            print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' complete')
        else:
            print('Row ' + str(insRow) + ' not complete')

        insRow += 1
```

Comment: Добавил изменения. Теперь просто пропускает все подряд ячейки, не находит нужного элемента(тега).

Comment: @Aleksey_G, вопрос был о причине этой ошибке и я показал почему возникает и как исправить. А почему так происходит... я бы смотрел что приходит с сайта (сохраняйте например в файлик) и изучил бы. Скорее всего, Sergey Gornostaev прав и сайт возвращает не то, что вы ожидаете